# Is it possible to have multiple tabs in one PowerShell terminal window on Windows 10?

Tags: windows, powershell, command-line, terminal, tabs

I need to work with several terminal windows simultaneously, and it's very inconvenient to constantly have to switch between different terminal windows. Is there a way to have multiple tabs in one window? I know it's possible on [macOS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zdwq5.png) and Linux, but can't figure out how to configure that on Windows 10.

Comment: You may use the new [Windows Terminal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Terminal) ... available for version from 1909 and up.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

### Yes.

You can use [The new Windows Terminal](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/windows-terminal/9n0dx20hk701) or [VSCode](https://www.google.com/search?q=vscode) Integrated Terminal.

---

### Windows Terminal:

In the new terminal app, you can have multiple PowerShell profiles as tabs.

so that you can work with several terminal tabs simultaneously.

The UI looks like browser tabs. You can download it from the [Microsoft store](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/windows-terminal/9n0dx20hk701) or [Github](https://github.com/Microsoft/Terminal).

[image: Visual screen snip of powershell profiles in windows new ternmial app]screen snip of powershell profiles in Windows ternmial downloaded from Microsoft store.

---

### VSCode:

In [Visual Studio Code](https://www.google.com/search?q=vscode), open New Terminal from Terminal Menu on Top bar.

On the right, you can Maximize panel size and can choose the terminal profiles.

The best thing about this vscode terminals is...

Along with seeing them as tabs in the right side, you can split them side by side and work on them at same time.

[image: Visual screen snip of powershell and different profiles in VSCode Integrated terminal maximized]
snip of multiple Powershells and other profiles in VSCode Integrated terminal panel maximized

Comment: Why did Microsoft make a fourth terminal app instead of just adding the features to any of the existing ones? And then why didn't they install this one with a Windows Update like they already do with cmd and powershell anyways? Anyways, downloaded and it looks nice. Automatically picked up my powershell profile and ran its startup scripts so that's nice.

Comment: This new terminal app is just a skin. Everything inside the terminal uses the default cmd or PowerShell as a skeleton. They might make it inbuilt in windows 11 as far as I know they are transitioning to push everything through store updates instead of windows updates. The old terminals are not going anywhere as they are as simple as they come and less confusing for some people.